# TypeScript: How to create readonly numerically indexed object

Tags: typescript, indexing, readonly

In an app using WebSockets, I want to map socket-close codes to strings so that on close event, I can get the message from the numeric code. At the moment I'm just exporting an object from a "constants" module, like so:

```
export const CloseCodes: { [index: number]: string } = {
    1000: "Normal closure",
    1001: "The endpoint is going away",
    1002: "The endpoint is terminating"
    // etc.
}
```

On socket close, I can map the `event.code` to a string via `CloseCodes[event.code]`, which is what I want, but I can also do `CloseCodes[event.code] = "garbage"`, `CloseCodes[1234]="hello"` and `delete(CloseCodes[event.code])`, all of which are undesirable. Is there a way to create a read-only numerically indexed structure for this type of usage? I'm looking for a TypeScript way of doing this, not an ES6 `Object.defineProperty(...)` way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply declare it with a [readonly index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532):

```
export const CloseCodes: { readonly [index: number]: string } = {
    1000: "Normal closure",
    1001: "The endpoint is going away",
    1002: "The endpoint is terminating"
    // etc.
}

// Both "Index signature in type '{ readonly [index: number]: string; }' only permits reading." errors:
CloseCodes[1000] = "bad";  // error!
delete CloseCodes[1000];  // error!
```

I believe using `readonly` in the way shown above was introduced in TypeScript 2.0, so you'll need to be using at least that version of TypeScript. Also note that disallowing the delete operator [was a very recent TypeScript change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11990), so you might not see this behavior yet in your project.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I don't get an error with `delete WsCloseCodes[1000];` though, not sure why since I'm running TypeScript 2.1.4. Either way, this is what I was looking for.